# How to check if visitor is logged in and if yes set a variable to determine further actions

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5 and in the head of my site I have a module with the following code:

```
        <?php
$user =JFactory::getUser()->guest;
    if ($user->guest) {
      echo 'Please sign up or sign in to view this'
    }
    else {
      echo 'Here is the content';
    }
       ?>
```

What I tried but didnt work is to add a variable $member in the first if statement. If the person isnt logged in to show him the echo but also set $member to == true.

Why I want to do this? I think it would make the site load faster if I check the status of $member than to go calling the Joomla API to determine if the user is logged in or not.

The calls to determine if a visitor is a member or not in every page are about 5-7. When I use the JFactory::getUser() function (all of the code above) 5-7 times it does slow down a bit the website. Thats why I thought of creating in the first call the $member == true correct me if I am wrong in thinking this would be better in site perfomance/speed wise.

I tried this:

```
        <?php
$user =JFactory::getUser()->guest;
    if ($user->guest) {
      echo 'Please sign up or sign in to view this'
      $member == true;
    }
    else {
      echo 'Here is the content';
    }
       ?>
```

I have the above code in the header module. But when I later in other modules in the same page or in the article if I use a php code it doesn't recognize the status of $member and always determines the user as not logged in.

What am I doing wrong? I'm guessing its something with variables scope, I checked my PHP book but couldn't find the error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would be really surprised if this change will have any measurable effect, let alone a significant one. Please share your findings.

Comment: $user =JFactory::getUser()->guest;
    if ($user->guest)  doesn't make sense  ..... 
$user =JFactory::getUser()
if ($user->guest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already calling `$user->guest`, so try changing:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser()->guest;
```

to this:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

As an alternative, you could also do use the following:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->id=0){
    echo 'Please sign up or sign in to view this'
    $member == true;
}
else {
    echo 'Here is the content';
}
```

Comment: I tried the code but when I have inside the article the code 
if ($member == true)
  {
  echo "Here is the content";
  } 
else
{
echo "Please sign up or sign in to view this";
}

But it always determines that $member is not logged in even though I am.

Comment: Why are you using `$member == true;` ?

Comment: Instead of calling multiple times in the pages the JFactory..blabla the script above. I thought to call it only once and then asign a variable $member the value true or false depending on wether the member is logged in or not. That way it would be faster to just check the further down the page in other modules and article the $member variable if its true or not than to go through JFactory... 5-7 times. In order to optimize the website better for speed. I pasted here the whole code and some notes of the concept of the code mate, http://pastebin.com/dYvCtvSZ

Comment: I am using http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla/DirectPHP-plugin.php and I am using it in a module I added in the very top in the template so it get executed first when being parsed and then the rest of the content.

Comment: Nope, through the module manager and inside it I added the php code. Also the second part where I check the status of $member I add it in the article and also in another module inside the article (using modules anywhere).

Comment: Instead if always using `if ($member = true){ echo "The content"; }`, simply use `if ($user->guest){ echo "The content"; }`. There is no point assigning another variable when you can use built in Joomla methods

Comment: Doesnt this slow down the website everytime calling the Joomla API to check the $user->guest ? Thats why I thought to assign another variable to be faster and less queries to the server. I need to determine about 5-7 times in each page if the user is logged in or not and that puts a bit more pressure on the pageload. Correct me if I am wrong please, its just a wild theory I have towards speed optimizing everything.

Comment: No, it won't, as assigning the variable `$member` will also have to make this check.

Comment: but doesn't the code in the first make an sql query to the server to check the member id while the $member doesnt? Also may I move this to chat to avoid dragging the post so long?

Comment: Ill just use multiple instances of the above code including the JFactory::GetUser cause without it simple $user->guest wont give correct results. Thanks Lodder, you have helped me once again. Take care.

Comment: GetUser actually caches the results for each user id that is called (or in this case no user id, so the current user) so each subsequent call does not have to go back to the database. It should be just as fast as checking versus a local variable except you won't have any scope issues , since you can use `JFactory::getUser` anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the Reply David, so if I use multiple times in the article this code -> pastebin.com/MKh9UnkG It wont call multiple times the server?

Comment: Hell no. And there is probably no reason to assign the Boolean value to `$user`, either. Give the Joomla devs _some_ credit :) (And check out the `Factory` design pattern)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in one line, Refactored code would be

```
  $member = (JFactory::getUser()->id) ? true : false ;
```